# Adding a JButton when another JButton is pressed

Tags: java, swing, button, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a JButton which I want to create a new JButton with when it is pressed I have added an ActionListener that looks like this, but it doesn't add another JButton.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Object command = e.getSource();
        if(command.equals(play)){
            ImageIcon i1 = new ImageIcon("NewGame.png");
            width = i1.getIconWidth();
            height = i1.getIconWidth();
            newGame = new JButton(i1);
            newGame.setBorderPainted(false);
            newGame.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            newGame.setSize(width, height);
            newGame.setLocation(600,100);
            add(newGame);
            System.out.println("It Works");
        } 
    }
```

How would I make it so that when I press the already existing JButton this one will be added?

Comment: when you say it wont work, what error do you get?

Comment: @rahulmaindargi it just doesn't add the JButton

Comment: And how did you put the listener on the first button?

Comment: you are adding it to the container that has the action listener. You should keep a reference to the container that you want to add it to and add it there. depends on layout manager etc. You understand this will happen everytime?

Comment: will help if you give more of the relevant code so we do not have to guess. calling invalidate might help too.

Comment: Since you are not painting the borders or adding an ActionListener to the button, I would use a JLabel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to `revalidate` and `repaint` after adding the button

```
revalidate();
repaint();
```

From the use of `setSize` and `setLocation`, it appears you are using a absolute positioning or `null` layout. Use a layout manager.

Answer (score 0):

You must call `repaint()` after adding it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not getting exception, then you will need to refresh or repaint the container which will old the new button.